# TypeError: fun() takes at least 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, typeerror, python-decorators

This is my code:

```
def fun(x, y, b=None, c=None): 
    print(x,' ',y,' ',b,' ',c)
```

I am calling it as `fun(1, b=2, c=4)` and getting error `TypeError: fun() takes at least 2 arguments (3 given)`.
I know this error is because of incorrect number of positional and keyword arguments.

Instead of this, I want whenever I call my function with incorrect no. of arguments, it should tell me which argument is provided.
For example: for above case it should say something like "argument y is nor provided".

Can I write a decorator for this purpose?

Comment: Please post your code otherwise we can't help.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to happen instead. Please clarify " I want to handle this error and prompt error like it requires these (names) positional arguments."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to handle this error and prompt error like it requires these (names) positional arguments. Is it possible to write a decorator for this?

I did a bit of research and came across the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module. Perhaps something along these lines will suffice? Right now I'm catching `TypeError` and printing a message, but you may prefer throwing a new `TypeError` that contains the message instead.

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps


def inspect_signature(f):
    signature = inspect.signature(f)

    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        except TypeError:
            print('Failed to call "{}" with signature {}. Provided args={} and kwargs={}.'.format(
                f.__name__, signature, args, kwargs))

    return decorator


@inspect_signature
def func(foo, bar):
    print('Called successfully with foo={}, bar={}'.format(foo, bar))
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    func(foo='a', bar='b')
    func(foo='a')
    func('a', 'b', 'c')
```

**Output**

```
Called successfully with foo=a, bar=b
Failed to call "func" with signature (foo, bar). Provided args=() and kwargs={'foo': 'a'}.
Failed to call "func" with signature (foo, bar). Provided args=('a', 'b', 'c') and kwargs={}.
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7. It does not support inspect.signature()

Comment: @python_user (1) Please don't use Python 2. Let it die. (2) What about `inspect.getargspec`? I tried that first but it said it was deprecated.

Comment: One thing more, how can I preserve function signature?

Comment: @python_user What do you mean?

Comment: try to print `inspect.getargspec(func)` after your function call. You willl get empty argspec like this`ArgSpec(args=[], varargs='args', keywords='kwargs', defaults=None)`.

Comment: @python_user Really not sure what you mean. I've tried out `getargspec` and moved it around and I don't get the same output as you. Update your question with the exact code you're running right now, as well as the outputs you're getting.

Comment: I got it. You are not getting the problem because you are using python 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

`fun` as defined need to get between 2 and 4 argument, as it has two mandatory arguments and two optional arguments. You did not provide one of the two mandatory ones:

```
fun(1, b=2, c=4) # What about the argument y?
```

You need to call it using one of the next forms:

```
fun(1, 2)
fun(1, 2, b=3)
fun(1, 2, c=4)
fun(1, 2, b=3, c=4)
```

---

If you want notification about insufficient arguments, you can use `args` and `kwargs`:

```
def fun(*args, **kwargs):

    if len(args) < 2:
        print("Need at least two arguments!"); return
    if len(args) > 2 or len(kwargs) > 2:
        print("Too much arguments supplied!"); return

    x, y = args
    a, b = kwargs.get('a', None), kwargs.get('b', None)

    print(x, y, a, b)
```